# Perfomance hit: application, hardware or settings?

Tags: performance, okular

16.04 on 8GB RAM, SSD Intel:

```
$ lscpu
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                8
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-7
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    4
Socket(s):             1
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 30
Model name:            Intel(R) Core(TM) i7 CPU       Q 740  @ 1.73GHz
Stepping:              5
CPU MHz:               933.000
CPU max MHz:           1734.0000
CPU min MHz:           933.0000
BogoMIPS:              3457.79
Virtualization:        VT-x
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              6144K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-7
Flags:                 fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt lahf_lm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid dtherm ida
```

An epub reader (Okular) was installed and despite being set to performance, it takes significant time advancing the document's pages.  Frequently freezing or "greying out": it seems that the text is decoded from a .jpg source however, I am fairly certain that .epub documents are not encoded in  this manner.  The rendering speed is annoying enough to warrant posting this message in search of understanding the problem.

Update: system monitor shows a single CPU spike when Okular is non-responsive

## QUESTION

Although the CPU clock rate is 0.9-1.7GHz, can I eliminate the hardware as the cause of slow rendering?  Any suggestions to speedup rendering such that it is usable is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: I don't know if it comes as a consolation, but even on my very decent machine page changes are noticeably slow and I can easily max out the CPU meter on my 3.3Ghz CPU by just keeping the PageDown key pressed. Seems to be a [know nproblem](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=359932). Of course you won't get a better version on 16.04 but you may fnd a more recent version on [UbuntuUpdates](https://ubuntuupdates.org/)

Comment: @xenoid Thanks for the test results: can you post your RAM quantity and if you are using an SSD.  If I had to guess, your configuration exceeds mine

Comment: Core i7-6820HQ, 32GB RAM, SSD, so when something is slow, I can't blame it on the hardware :)

Comment: Update: removed Okular and installed fbreader - acceptable performance on modest hardware